# Is there a faster way to test if two lists have the exact same elements than Pythons built in == operator?

Tags: python

If I have two lists, each 800 elements long and filled with integers. Is there a faster way to compare that they have the exact same elements (and short circuit if they don't) than using the built in `==` operator?

```
a = [6,2,3,88,54,-486]
b = [6,2,3,88,54,-486]
a == b 
>>> True
```

Anything better than this?

I'm curious only because I have a *giant* list of lists to compare.

Comment: are the lists sorted?

Comment: @ChrisPalmer Nay. It's a big list of histogram values, so they're unsorted.

Comment: I don't think it would matter if they were sorted.

Comment: @ChrisPalmer: it really shouldn't matter. The comparison cannot be done faster than a single linear pass on both lists, which is what I assume Python does under the hood anyways

Comment: Aren't histogram's sorted by time or some x value?

Comment: @ZackYoshyaro: The answer is no. The question is: Why do you need it to be faster?

Comment: If you perform many more equality comparisons than list updates, then you can compute a hash value for each list and compare those for equality.

Comment: I only point it out because the equality test in Python when comparing dictionaries is to compare them out of order, but with things like arrays I think it already short circuits at the first hint that they arent equal

Comment: The first optimization that comes to mind is parallelization with threads.

Comment: Given that the elements are guaranteed to be integers and that the lists are the same length, one possible approach would be to check that each element of one list is `in` the other list. This avoids having to sort either list, but I don't know how it compares in terms of efficiency.

Comment: @inspector for 800 elements, the overhead of threads will be drastically in excess of the gain.

Comment: @ZackYoshyaro The reason I ask is that although there is no faster way to compare two lists, there are faster ways to compare, say **200** lists.

Comment: When you say the lists are equal, are you just refering to the lists containing the same items or that they contain the same items at the same index?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's not assume, but run some tests!

The set-up:

```
>>> import time
>>> def timeit(l1, l2, n):
        start = time.time()
        for i in xrange(n):
                l1 == l2
        end = time.time()
        print "%d took %.2fs" % (n, end - start)
```

Two giant equal lists:

```
>>> hugeequal1 = [10]*30000
>>> hugeequal2 = [10]*30000
>>> timeit(hugeequal1, hugeequal2, 10000)
10000 took 3.07s
```

Two giant lists where the first element is not equal:

```
>>> easydiff1 = [10]*30000
>>> easydiff2 = [10]*30000
>>> easydiff2[0] = 0
>>> timeit(easydiff1, easydiff2, 10000)
10000 took 0.00s
>>> timeit(easydiff1, easydiff2, 1000000)
1000000 took 0.14s
```

So it appears the built-in list equality operator does indeed do the short-circuiting.

EDIT: Interestingly, using the `array.array` module doesn't make it any faster:

```
>>> import array
>>> timeit(hugeequal1, hugeequal2, 1000)
1000 took 0.30s
>>> timeit(array.array('l', hugeequal1), array.array('l', hugeequal2), 1000)
1000 took 1.11s
```

`numpy` does get you a good speed-up, though:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> timeit(hugeequal1, hugeequal2, 10000)
10000 took 3.01s
>>> timeit(numpy.array(hugeequal1), numpy.array(hugeequal2), 10000)
10000 took 1.11s
```

Comment: So if the list is often different, the == operator on a normal list is great. I'm curious what if the list is often equal, but we need to check anyways. What could we do if that's the case?

Comment: @Calyth: Hmm, if the list is likely to match something you've seen before, you could compute a hash of the list, and then compare the hashes instead of the lists themselves.

Comment: Yeah. Mentally I as wondering whether the hashing at __eq__() time would be more expensive than actually comparing the list manually. Then I thought maybe if we kept a hash as items are added, but then it was hitting lots of snag. I should really just try it out like you said ;)

Comment: @Calyth: what's your exact use case? if the list could be one of 100 possible lists, for example, it's probably cheaper (can test it out) to have hashes of the 100, then hash each new list as it's coming in & check against the other 100 hashes with a dict or a set than to do 100 list comparisons. and if none of them match you know the list is different too.

Comment: @Calyth: actually you will still have to compare the lists if the hashes match cause there might be hash collisions, unlikely as it is..

Answer (score 4):

[**Numpy**](http://www.numpy.org/) can speed this up 10x, and is particularly relevant since your lists are of a fix (integer) type.

In pure python, each comparison has to follow a reference to the next elements, check the types, etc.  In numpy, only a pointer needs to be incremented.

Here's a comparison:

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import timeit

N = 10**7

p0 = list(range(N))
p1 = list(range(N))

n0 = np.arange(N)
n1 = np.arange(N)

number = 500
t = timeit("p0==p1", setup="from __main__ import p0, p1", number=number)
print "pure python time =", t/number

number = 500
t = timeit("(n0==n1).all()", setup="from __main__ import n0, n1", number=number)
print "numpy time =", t/number
```

And the result is 10x faster using numpy:

```
pure python time = 0.256077399254
numpy time = 0.0286148643494
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use [pypy](http://pypy.org/):

```
$ python -mtimeit -s 'a=[10]*30000;b=[10]*30000;print(a==b)'
100000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0104 usec per loop

$ pypy -mtimeit -s 'a=[10]*30000;b=[10]*30000;print(a==b)'
1000000000 loops, best of 3: 0.00102 usec per loop
```

And, pypy performs 10x faster for this input.

Answer (score 3):

The built in features of CPython (which I assume you're using) tend be written in C.  So you won't get much faster then that unless you write some C/C++ code that exploits some aspect of your context.

Comment: Algorithms are just as important as implementation language in many cases.

Comment: And if low-latency really matters, that algorithm will *always* run faster in C/C++ than Python.

Comment: That may be so, but I take issue with the implication that implementation language is the most important technique.

Comment: I can't believe six people thought this was an answer worth upvoting.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to make the comparison if two lists faster. But you say you have a giant list of lists. And that sounds like you are asking the wrong question. And if we assume that what you want is to find which lists in your list of lists that are the same, then yes, there is a faster way to do that:

```
>>> list_of_lists = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7], [1,3,3,4,5,6,7], [1,2,3,4,5,6,6], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]]
>>> list_of_hashes = [hash(tuple(x)) for x in list_of_lists]
>>> list_of_hashes
[1738718158840515323, -9068250430673137562, 1738718158842010488, 1738718158840515323]
```

As you see here, I make a hash out of each list (I have to make them into tuples first, because lists are not hashable). Then comparing is trivial, as you now have just a list of integers instead of a list of lists. If you don't care about the order of the items in the list use `hash(set(x))` instead.

```
>>> list_of_hashes[0] == list_of_hashes[1]
False
>>> list_of_hashes[0] == list_of_hashes[2]
False
>>> list_of_hashes[0] == list_of_hashes[3]
True
```

This is much faster if you have many long lists and you are comparing all lists to all other lists.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way. The only way to know whether two items are equal is to compare them, and you have to compare all pairs to know if they're equal.

That said, you may be able to get a speedup anyway. If you use NumPy ndarrays properly, NumPy can speed up not just your comparisons, but pretty much everything else you do with your data. Alternatively, if there's some external information you can use, or some relation between whether one pair of lists compares equal and whether another pair does, you may be able to exploit that information to avoid some of the comparison work.

Comment: To clarify `==` does short-circuit? e.g. `[1,2,3] == [2,3,4]` will short-circuit after comparing the first (0th) element 1 != 2?

Comment: @Chris_Rands: It does.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your usecase, you could switch to using tuples (which are not mutable), and put the lists in a set.

Your other option is to keep track of similarity (or not) as you build up the lists.