# Difference between Python2 and Python3 while using map with find and index

Tags: python, python-3.x, map-function

Given a pattern and a string `str`, find if `str` follows the same pattern.

Here follows means a full match, such that there is a bijection between a letter in pattern and a non-empty word in `str`.

Examples:
`pattern = "abba"`, `str = "dog cat cat dog"` should return true; `dog` is `a`, `cat` is `b` and the words form the `abba` pattern.
`pattern = "abba"`, `str = "dog cat cat fish"` should return false; the string follows a `abbc` pattern instead.

My solution works in Python 2:

```
def wordPattern(self, pattern, str):
    s = pattern
    t = str.split()
    return map(s.find, s) == map(t.index, t)
```

But I am just wondering why this solution  does not working in Python 3. There, the function will always return `False` when trying to test the above examples. Could anyone please give some advice?

Comment: map returns a generator in python 3

Comment: Use list(map(...))

Answer (score 10):

In Python 3, `map()` returns an iterator object, not a list. Equality testing between these objects won't work (equality is testing for *identity*, the exact same object in memory, instead).

Convert to lists explicitly:

```
def wordPattern(self, pattern, str):
    s = pattern
    t = str.split()
    return list(map(s.find, s)) == list(map(t.index, t))
```

or use list comprehensions:

```
def wordPattern(self, pattern, str):
    s = pattern
    t = str.split()
    return [s.find(c) for c in  s] == [t.index(w) for w in t]
```

or avoid creating lists altogether by comparing the zipped results with the [`all()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all):

```
from operator import eq
from itertools import starmap, zip_longest

def wordPattern(self, pattern, str):
    s = pattern
    t = str.split()
    return all(starmap(eq, zip_longest(map(s.find, s), map(t.index, t))))
```

The latter short-circuits without having to make all comparisons if there is no match. In the spirit of keeping the functional style, I used [`itertools.starmap()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) to test for equality with the [`operator.eq()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.eq). By using [`itertools.zip_longest()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) we make sure that we can detect the case where the pattern length and word count don't match.

Comment: thanks for the corrections :) yours already tells the story to tell so mine is superflous.

Comment: I heard that `list1 == list2` comparisons short circuit too, is that right? see comment here https://stackoverflow.com/a/18410924/6260170

Comment: @Chris_Rands: it does, but you first have to do two full iterations to *create the lists*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think that the last solution only works if `s` and `t` have the same number of elements. Did I miss something?

Comment: wordPattern(None, "abba", "dog cat cat dog dog") should return false and the last example returns true. You should check the number of elements first, i think

Comment: The reason is that the `zip` function stops when iteration on one argument is done. additional elements on the other arguments are ignored

Comment: @luc: yes, I know *why* :-P

Comment: @MartijnPieters : with 622k of reputation, i imagine that you know it :-) Just explaining for any other wondering why. Thanks for edit and solution.